# Recommended reverse firewall applications for linux?

Tags: linux, software-rec, firewall

I'm looking for a reverse firewall, something like [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) for Linux, but my google-fu is failing me. Does something like this exist on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

TuxGuardian won't compile on newer kernels.

LeopardFlower over at sf.net is the closest you can get for Linux nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

TuxGuardian is the closest thing I've seen to Little Snitch for Linux:

http://tuxguardian.sourceforge.net/