# How to build an equivalent of littlesnitch or zonealarm under linux?

Tags: linux, firewall

The question : [Recommended reverse firewall applications for linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20900/recommended-reverse-firewall-applications-for-linux?rq=1) asks for a reverse firewall used to monitor, preventing or permitting network access, at the process level, with a GUI. There is two such applications namely [TuxGuardian](http://tuxguardian.sourceforge.net/) and [LeopardFlower](http://sourceforge.net/projects/leopardflower/) but they are no more  maintained.

My question is the following : How can we combine existing tools and libraries to build a similar application under linux with a GUI or a text based interface?

Comment: This question asks how to combine existing tools and not for dedicated reverse firewall applications.